# NameError: global name 'flash' is not defined

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm learning databases by building a basic Flask Application by following this tutorial here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sqlalchemy.htm and I am currently at the point where I need to make a connection to my SQLITE3 database via  SQLAlchemy. To be honest it's not going that well. I got this error:  NameError: global name 'flash' is not defined

Here's my **app.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sqlite3



conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')




app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///students.sqlite3'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Students(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('student_id',db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Students %r>' % self.name


db.create_all()


@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')




@app.route('/new', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def new():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      if not request.form['name'] or not request.form['id']:
         flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')
      else:
         student = Students(request.form['name'], request.form['id'])
         db.session.add(student)
         db.session.commit()

         flash('Record was successfully added')
         return redirect(url_for('show_all'))
   return render_template('new.html')



@app.route("/admin")
def show_all():
   return render_template('show_all.html', students = students.query.all() )



    # create user code will be here !!


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Attendance System</title>


    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Sign In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="new">Sign Up</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h3 class="text-muted">Python Flask App</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Attendance App</h1>
            <p class="lead"></p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="new" role="button">Sign up today</a>
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="show_all" role="button">Administrate</a>
            </p>
        </div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <p>&copy; Company 2015</p>
        </footer>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**show_all.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">
       <head></head>
       <body>

          <h3>
             <a href = "{{ url_for('show_all') }}">Comments - Flask 
                SQLAlchemy example</a>
          </h3>

          <hr/>
          {%- for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
             {{ message }}
          {%- endfor %}

          <h3>Students (<a href = "{{ url_for('new') }}">Add Student
             </a>)</h3>

          <table>
             <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Id</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>

             <tbody>
                {% for student in students %}
                   <tr>
                      <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
                      <td>{{ student.id }}</td>

                {% endfor %}
             </tbody>
          </table>

       </body>
    </html>

**new.html**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>

      <h3>Attendance</h3>
      <hr/>

      {%- for category, message in get_flashed_messages(with_categories = true) %}
         <div class = "alert alert-danger">
            {{ message }}
         </div>
      {%- endfor %}

      <form action = "{{ request.path }}" method = "post">
         <label for = "name">Name</label><br>
         <input type = "text" name = "name" placeholder = "Name" /><br>
         <label for = "id">Id Number</label><br>
         <input type = "text" name = "id" placeholder = "Student Id" /><br>
         <input type = "submit" value = "Sign-in!" />

      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Problem:

I don't know if the connection works or not, even if the error get's fixed the `NameError` one  since it's a first for me, at first I tried using MySQL but flask.ext.mysql is deprecated, so I tried switching to SQLAlchemy and SQLite3. Any help is appreciated for a newbie like me. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add `from flask import flash` to your code. All the HTML files are irrelevant to the question.